# nginx rewrite requests to remove unknown paths

Tags: php, docker, nginx, nginx-config

I have an application running in a docker container (webdevops/php-nginx) thinking it runs at the root path, f.ex.

```
http://localhost:8000/index.php
```

In front of the application I am running an external load balancer and giving each application a separate URI-path on the same host, f.ex:

```
http://localhost/app1/index.php should use the backendserver at http://localhost:8000
```

When the request comes into my application, it will be http://localhost:8000/app1/index.php, but I want my nginx to strip the /app1/ part (the first path segment). I won't know the content of the path segment on beforehand.

The following table shows some examples:

```
+------------------------------------------------_+----------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|                  Incoming URL                   |         File tried         | File exists? |       File used       |
+------------------------------------------------_+----------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| http://localhost:8000/                          | /index.php                 | N            | /index.php            |
| http://localhost:8000/app1/                     | /app1/index.php            | N            | /index.php            |
| http://localhost:8000/css/base.css              | /css/base.css              | Y            | /css/base.css         |
| http://localhost:8000/app1/edit.php             | /app1/edit.php             | N            | /edit.php             |
| http://localhost:8000/app1/css/base.css         | /app1/css/base.css         | N            | /css/base.css         |
| http://localhost:8000/app1/foo/bar/css/base.css | /app1/foo/bar/css/base.css | N            | /foo/bar/css/base.css |
+------------------------------------------------_+----------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

I have tried the following config:

### /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ ^/([^/]+/)(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$2 /index.php?$query_string;
```

### /opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/10-php.conf

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

### /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-php.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}
```

and it works for serving static files, but any PHP-files served second location-statement stopped working.

I'm sure there is a trivial solution to this, but I'm kind of stumped right now.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a possible solution adding a second location statement which seems to do what I want:

### /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/(?:[^/]+)/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$2;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}
location ~ ^/([^/]+/)(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$2 /index.php?$query_string;
```